# R: Checking dataframe value in "if" statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I need to fix a mistake in how data was entered in a column, so I wrote a set of "if" statements in a while loop to fix it. But the equal sign in `if(df1[n,2] = 1)` causes an error. What do I need to change?

```
while(n<=424){
    if(df1[n,2] = 1){
        df1[n+1,2] <- df1[1,2]
        df1[n+2,2] <- df1[1,2]
        n <- n+3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` in R is for assignment, `==` tests for equality

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
if(df1[n,2] == 1)
```